CS to Astrophysics
I’m 46 years old and got my bachelors degree in computer science from WGU in 6 months. I want to do a PhD in computational astrophysics. I was originally go to double majoring in undergrad but saw this opportunity. What is the best path? Bridge program?

What concretely is the question? How to get admitted? How to actually finish it? How to live of a grad student's salary again at 46?

You did a four-year degree in six months, so a PhD should take only about 8 months, right? :-)

But seriously, there is no special pipeline for 46-years-olds with CS degrees from WGU. You should look at the PhD programs you want to apply to and figure out how to make yourself competitive. The above-linked "canonical question" explains the process. Then come back when you have more specific questions.
